# solving 1D Schrödinger equation with Numerov method (python)

Tags: python, math, physics, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I'm currently trying to solve the 1D Schrödinger eq. (time independent) with the Numerov method. The derivation of the method is clear to me but I have some problems with the implementation. I tried to look for solutions on google, and there are some ([like this one](http://mtdevans.com/2013/07/solving-the-schrodinger-equation-with-numerovs-algorithm/) or [this one](http://physics.oregonstate.edu/%7Elandaur/Books/CPbook/eBook/Codes/PythonCodes/QuantumNumerov.py)), but I don't really understand what they are doing in their codes...

The Problem:

With some math you can get the equation to this form:
[image]
where [image]. For the beginning I'd like to look at the potential `V(x)=1 if -a<x<a`.

Since I don't have values for the energy or the first values of Psi (which are needed to start the algorithm) I just guessed some...

The code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.constants import hbar

m= 1e-27
E= 0.5

def numerov_step(psi_1,psi_2,k1,k2,k3,h):
    #k1=k_(n-1), k2=k_n, k3=k_(n+1)
    #psi_1 = psi_(n-1) and psi_2=psi_n
    m = 2*(1-5/12. * h**2 * k2**2)*psi_2
    n = (1+1/12.*h**2*k1**2)*psi_1
    o = 1 + 1/12. *h**2 *k3**2
    return (m-n)/o

def numerov(N,x0,xE,a):
    x,dx = np.linspace(x0,xE,N+1,retstep=True)

    def V(x,a):
        if (np.abs(x)<a):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    
    k = np.zeros(N+1)
    for i in range(len(k)):
        k[i] = 2*m*(E-V(x[i],a))/hbar**2

    psi= np.zeros(N+1)
    psi[0]=0
    psi[1]=0.1    

    for j in np.arange(2,N):
        psi[j+1]= numerov_step(psi[j],psi[j+1],k[j-1],k[j],k[j+1],dx)

    return psi

x0 =-10
xE = 10
N =1000

psi=numerov(N,x0,xE,3)

x = np.linspace(x0,xE,N+1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,psi)
plt.show()
```

Since the plot doesn't look like a wavefunction at all something has to be wrong, but I'm having trobule to find out what it is.. Would be nice if someone could help a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't quite remember the quantum physics so I don't understand some details. Still I see some bugs in your code:

1. Why inside `numerov_step` you square `k1`, `k2` and `k3`?
2. In your main cycle

```python
   for j in np.arange(2,N):
      psi[j+1]= numerov_step(psi[j],psi[j+1],k[j-1],k[j],k[j+1],dx)
```

you messed up with indices. It looks like this line should be

```
   for j in np.arange(2, N):
     psi[j] = numerov_step(psi[j - 2], psi[j - 1], k[j - 2], k[j - 1], k[j], dx)
```

3. This is the part I don't really understand. Looking into animation at your [first link](http://mtdevans.com/2013/07/solving-the-schrodinger-equation-with-numerovs-algorithm/) it looks like this equation has good solutions only for certain combinations of `V(x)` and `E` and in other cases it quickly goes wild. It looks like both your `V(x)` and proportion of `E`  to `hbar` and `V(x)` are quite different from the referenced articles and this might be one more reason why the solution goes wild.

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment. I corrected my code according to your suggestions. 

1) I was referencing a slightly different paper with a different definiton of k... 

2) This was probbably the main mistake, so thanks for that!

3) after changing the mass and hbar to one (asked the TA) I get at least something that looks like a wavefunction... 

I'll probbably try out some more Potentials and see what happens, if more questions arise I'll poste them here as well